# The problem with K-means Clustering including Conditions

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data set (more than 1000 samples) including 2 dimensionals (x, y) like (P, cospi) with (0<=P<=maxP; 0<=cospi<=1). Now, my task is to cluster this data set following the condition that is depend on time ( Idle and peak). Does anyone have any idea to help me out of this problem.

Comment: In clustering algorithm you just need to define a mathematical distance between your elements

Comment: You can [dummy encode](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) your time variable; idle and peak can be dummy encoded with a `is_peak` variable. Then, apply the  k-means algorithm separately to your idle data set and to your peak data dataset.